# Codeigniter, Dynamic Menus From the Database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am Trying to Implement the Dynamic Menus

i Have two Tables in my Database
`pbs_forms` includes Form Path Form Path link etc
[image]

Second Table Name is `pbs_formsingroups`
it shows that form belongs to which group
[image]

Here is how right now i am getting data in my view

```
$GetForms=$this->CommonModel->get_by_join($columns,$PTable,$joins,$where);

foreach($GetForms as $key => $row){
    list($NavBar, $MainMenu, $SubMenu) = explode("/", $row['FormPath']);
    $arrayLeftMenuList = array();
    $arrayLeftMenuList[$key]['NavBarMenuLink'] = $NavBar;
    $arrayLeftMenuList[$key]['LeftMainMenu'] = $MainMenu;
    $arrayLeftMenuList[$key]['LeftSubMenu'] = $SubMenu;
    $arrayLeftMenuList[$key]['FormCIPath'] = $row['FormCIPath'];
    $arrayLeftMenuList[$key]['MainMenu_OrderNo'] = $row['Order_MainMenu_No'];
    $arrayLeftMenuList[$key]['SubMenu_OrderNo'] = $row['Order_SubMenu_No'];
    $arrayLeftMenuList[$key]['HaveSubMenus'] = $row['SubMenu'];
}
```

Data is Coming from the Database Fine..

Now When i Try This in Code:

```
foreach($arrayLeftMenuList as $key => $value){
    echo $arrayLeftMenuList[$key]['LeftSubMenu'];
}
```

In Result I only Get

```
Users
```

Instead I should Be Getting Both `Search Prize Bond` and `Users`?

Can Anyone Understand the Problem i have Stated above and Show me a solution that how to solve this issue?

Comment: post output from var_dump($arrayLeftMenuList);

Comment: @ahmad
Found My Problem Actually, It was replacing the second value with the First Because it was not Multi Dimentional Array Acctualy.. My Mistake..

I Added The Answer.
Thankyou for Response anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Mistake, 
Got The Solution, This was a Plain Mistake that i could not find before.

I changed

```
$arrayLeftMenuList = array();
```

to

```
$arrayLeftMenuList[$key] = array();
```

and now its working Great. :)